# How can the focal mechanism of an earthquake be determined from P-wave polarity?

Tags: seismology

I have data of P-wave polarity related to an earthquake. I tried to find the focal mechanism from the azimuth, takeoff angle, and P-wave polarity. I found that two packages, FOCMEC and HASHPY, are used, but I cannot get them to run properly. Is there any free software that I can use?

I am also looking for article or book that can explain the whole process of finding focal mechanism in greater detail.